# VS Code not recognizing a function returning `never` and giving "Object is possibly 'undefined'" error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

```
tsc --version: Version 2.5.2
Visual Studio Code Version: Version 1.16.1 (1.16.1) 27492b6bf3acb0775d82d2f87b25a93490673c6d
```

I am having some trouble with Visual Studio Code recognizing that I've tested for an object's nullability and it will `never` return if null.  VSCode will still believe that later uses of the object will possibly be null.

I can appreciate that it'd be difficult to detect this condition.  I had hoped that the `// @ts-ignore` would work in .ts files directly, as I'd really like to suppress/ignore this warning.

Consider the following `never` function and its use:

```js
function FatalError(message: string): never
{
 throw new Error(message);
}
interface ITest
{
 field1: number;
 field2: string;
}
function MyTest(args: ITest | null)
{
 var test: number;

 if (!args) FatalError("Unexpected value.");

 var test = args.field1;
}
MyTest({field1: 1, field2: "test"});
```

In VSCode, the red squiggly will appear under `args` of the `var test = args.field1;` line at the bottom, with the following:

```
[ts] Object is possibly 'null'.
(local var) test1: null
```

If I change my null check to something like the following:

```
if (!args) { FatalError("Unexpected value."); return; }
```

Then the compiler is satisfied that the null check has been done and the program control flow stops, such that subsequent uses of the variable avoid the `"Object is possibly 'null'"` error.  But, I feel like the `never` keyword should have accomplished the same thing.

What am I missing?

Edit:  my tsconfig.json settings are:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions":
  {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "es2015",
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Comment: In your `tsconfig.json` you could set `strictNullChecks` to `false`, but that would have the side effect of not enforcing whether values are null or undefined elsewhere (which may not be what you're looking for).

Answer (score 2):

It's a [design limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9655) in TypeScript, at least for now.  The compiler doesn't check that `FatalError()` returns `never` until after the control flow analysis is complete.  In that issue, the workaround is similar to what you have... something like:

```
if (!args) return FatalError("Unexpected value.");
```

So you're not really missing anything; it's just that the compiler isn't as smart as you are (it's trying, though!)  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz!  I wish, then, that we had the ability to suppress the the warning in a .ts file.  Maybe that feature is coming soon?

Comment: It seems the language designers are opposed to what you are suggesting on principle: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9448

Comment: Oh, interesting @winglerw28.  Hmmm...if the designers know that it can't catch everything, then they should allow the programmers to apply the appropriate remediation as necessary.